# JavaScript URL Search Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm having an odd issue with Regex string replacing in JavaScript. I have this Regex to search for URL's in a string that may contain multiple URL's (a comment or post, for instance):

`/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+/gi`

However I'm running into an issue where it will only match one URL...except when it doesn't. It's erratic, but in general it will only match one URL (not necessarily always the first one). Take this string:

```
"Test

http://google.com
http://google.com

http://google.com"
```

It will only match the first `http://google.com` instance.

The end goal is to replace URL's with links:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+/gi, '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>');
```

I'm using this to get a better idea of what is being matched and what is not:

```
function getMatches(re, str) {
    var matches = [],
        match;

    while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        matches.push(match[0]);
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT: It looks like there's something funny going on with my data that's causing the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pPR2A/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
str.replace(/(https?\:\/\/[^\s]+)/gi, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
```

Comment: My mistake, I am actually using that, just typed it wrong in the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of matches, you may try using [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) rather than `RegExp.exec`.

It can simplify `getMatches` to:

```
function getMatches(re, str) {
    var matches = str.match(re);
    return matches == null ? [] : matches;
}
```

Or possibly let you forgo it:

```
var matches = str.match(/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+/gi) || [];
```

You might also want to checkout tools like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) for quickly testing patterns, [such as yours](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cwww%5C.%29%5CS%2B&input=Test%0A%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%0A%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com).

Comment: Actually, it is needed when working with a Regular Expression using the g flag. Each successive call of exec will return a result array for each match (the match and then every captured parenthesis), so you have to look through until it returns null to get every match.

Comment: @coreyschram Ah. Sorry. I was thinking of [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which, with the global flag, will return all matches from the string.